# Allowing Enter Key and Click Function to both run

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the function:

```
    $(document).on('click keypress', '.pTile:not(.join)', function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode != 13) {
            return false;
        }
       //Do Stuff
    });
```

This code allows the user to either click the div or press the enter key. My problem, though, is that it really only allows the enter button due to the decision structure that filters the key code. How do I allow both the click and enter button event to go through?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery events have a `type` property which you can check:

```
$(document).on('click keypress', '.pTile:not(.join)', function (e) {
    if (e.type == 'keypress' && e.keyCode != 13) {
        return false;
    }
    //Do Stuff
});
```

Alternatively you could extract the logic to its own function and add separate handlers:

```
function doStuff() {
    // Do stuff...
}
$(document).on('click', '.pTile:not(.join)', doStuff);
$(document).on('keypress', '.pTile:not(.join)', function() {
    if (e.keyCode == 13)
        doStuff.call(this);
});
```

Comment: ... or `if(e.keyCode && e.keyCode != 13)` but your answer is recommended.